# Creación de modulo Auth STACK MEAN

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, jwt, autenticación

Hola equipo estoy profundizando en un proyecto que tengo con angular y tengo una pagina corporativa con la información de sus productos etc y un modulo de autenticación por medio del cual me despliega otras vistas para asignar tareas y adjuntar informes sobre obras de construcción. Solamente es para trabajadores de la empresa y administradores (los cuales crean roles, eliminan usuarios, crean tareas validan informes cargados entre otras funcionalidades), no se puede registrar cualquier persona en el aplicativo lo cual quiere decir que inicialmente debe haber registrado Por DB un admin para poder ingresar con su respectivo rol, como podría hacer eso ? es que encuentro mucha información en internet pero con el crud completo y no debe funcionar de esa forma porque el crud ya debe estar pero al momento de logear al admin.

solamente debería hacerme una api de consulta de usuario que inicialmente me valide el usuario y sus niveles de privilegio y esa misma api seria la que debería utilizar para el login de todos los usuarios en la app ?  si tienen alguna pagina, curso o video para evidenciar al menos la parte del back les agradezco

Intento realizar varios procesos pero no me sirve el crud que encuentro en las documentaciones que estoy observando debido a que se enfocan en el crud pero en lo que deseo hacer debe funcionar de otra manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]